# Rotating 3D Point around 3D Point using GLM

Tags: c++, math, rotation, glm-math

Is it possible to rotate a point around another point using GLM?

```
glm::vec3 point1(x1,y1,z1);
glm::vec3 point2(x2,y2,z2);
glm::vec3 angles(rX,rY,rZ);
glm::vec3 result = glm::rotate(point1, angles, point2);
```

Something along the lines of that, possible converting it to a `glm::mat4` beforehand?

Comment: You can't rotate anything around a point. Rotation is always about an axis. In the 2d case, the axis is perpendicular to the screen and reduces to a point. I couldn't find this instance of the `rotate` function in the glm doc. Is this even a valid call?

Comment: In this case I would be rotating it about the axis relative to both points. Such as axis = normal(point1 - point2) relative to point1. This is the function (http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.3/api/a00199.html)

Comment: But none of these functions take three vectors.